# Options for object creation are greyed out

Tags: interface, add-on, sapling-addon

I am trying to model a tree. I turned on the *Add a sapling* add-on in user preferences, however once I want to begin editing the settings, they come up but is grey and doesn't let me click on it.

[image: add sapling operator problem]

I have also attached my blend file here: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32199

Comment: Works for me, might be an issue with your Blender installation.

Comment: Hmm are there other ways to create a tree?

Comment: You could go through the time consuming process of manual modelling, better to check the console window for an error message, or reinstall.

Comment: you using 2.72?

Comment: Actually yes i am, the most recent verson

Comment: Do you have "global undo" in the user preferences turned off?

Comment: [same as this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8262/935)

Comment: Where would i find global undo?

Comment: ahh i have turned it on but it still doesnt work, do you think it's better to just re-install it?

Comment: @AyoAdelagun Perhaps you have a conflicting addon or something. Try loading factory settings (info header > file) then enabling only the sapling addon.

Answer (score 4):

You have to enable: **Global Undo**

For 2.8x and 2.9.

*Edit > User preferences > System > Memory & Limits: Global Undo*

[image]

For 2.79

You can do it in User Preferences (Ctrl+ Alt U), in "Editing" Tab.
[image: User Preferences/Editing - [check] Global Undo]

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that Global Undo is checked in User Preferences as mentioned above. Next, go to Settings in the Sapling: Add Tree region adjacent to the work window.  In the Settings, go to Branch Splitting.  Set the number of levels to 3 or more.  This will allow you to select a shape.