# Unselectable options when creating a new mesh

Tags: mesh, properties

Good day!
Blender 2.79.
When I create any new object by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (for instance, torus), I have panel "Add torus" unactivated. Can't click  **Generate UV's**, **Allign to View**, **Location**, etc.
What's wrong?
Thanks for answers.

Comment: Global undo needs to be enabled. See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/62656/935)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8262/what-is-causing-disabled-options-when-adding-a-mesh-curve-object-to-the-scene