# why the options to modify a primitive are grayed out in blender 2.75?

Tags: modeling, objects

[image: menu grayed out]

In blender 2.74 I can add a circle in object mode and change the number of sides, but in 2.75 I can't. I have to add the circle,enter edit mode and delete it, add it again and then i can edit. I add objects every second, I feel like I waste a lot of time. Is there a way to go back to the old behaviour?.

Comment: Is global undo disabled? in Ctrl Alt U > *User preferences*?

Comment: YEEES!!! THANKS!!! but I still don't understand why

Comment: wow, this is very old:
"With 2.35 Blender now offers a 'global undo' as well. It is called global, because it works outside of the temporal editing modes (like mesh editing or vertex paint) and restores on 'undo' the entire database of Blender."

Comment: I put a short explanation in my answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8263/599