# Blender 2.8 add object dialog disabled

Tags: objects

I'm using Blender for a couple of years now, and I recently installed Blender 2.8. I want to add a circle of 6 vertices, but when I add a circle, the 'Add Circle' dialog is disabled (screenshot below), and I can't change anything. This happens with every object I add to the scene. I haven't experienced anything like this in previous editions of Blender, and I can't find any setting to enable it. I've tried to restart Blender, and even reinstall it, but that didn't help. Is there any setting I'm missing that might be causing this?

[image]

Comment: ? I may be missing something, but the Circle dialog box is there in the lower left corner.  If you click the grey box with 32 in it, turn it black and delete the entry and retype it to "6" and hit enter, your circle should have 6 vertices.

Comment: No, that's just it, it seems disabled somehow. When I try to click anything in there, I just deselect the circle, as if the dialog wouldn't even be there. Also, it's displayed darker than normal. (compare the text in the dialog with the text in the timeline window below)

Comment: Have you tried to download and install a different iteration of  Blender 2.80?  It is still a beta and may not be entirely stable.  2.80 is being updated continually.  It could be worth a shot?

Comment: I've just installed the latest version of Blender 2.8 (2.80.55), still the same problem. Is there a way to get previous beta builds of Blender 2.8?

Comment: Similar issue? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38917/added-objects-properties-greyed-out?rq=1

Comment: Yes, thanks! Global Undo was unchecked. For anyone reading this in the future: this "Global Undo" setting isn't under the "Editing" tab like in 2.79 anymore, it has moved to the "System" tab.

Comment: load factory settings should help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, you need to go Edit->Preferences->System and then add the check to Global Undo