# How to make a checkbox in the Redo last panel editable?

Tags: python, scripting

In a class you can create a bool that shows up in the Redo last panel.

Example snippet:

```
deselect = BoolProperty(name="Deselect", default=False)
```

Unfortunately this checkbox is not editable in the Redo Last panel then. It is greyed out. Is there a way to make it editable?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is causing disabled options when adding a mesh/curve object to the scene?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8262/what-is-causing-disabled-options-when-adding-a-mesh-curve-object-to-the-scene)

Comment: Seems so. So i need to expand my question. How can i add Redo to the code so that i can toggle the edit box? Current bl_options are : bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'} . The try to add redo here too gives an error. ValueError: validating class:: 'REDO' not found in ('REGISTER', 'UNDO', 'BLOCKING', 'MACRO', 'GRAB_CURSOR', 'PRESET', 'INTERNAL')

Comment: It isn't your code, it is blender's user settings that disable the redo options. If it does happen to be only your operator that fails while others work, then adding your operator code may help see why it isn't working.

Comment: Hm. It's the Blender deselect bool from view3d.paint_select. Seems that i have to find another way then. Thanks :)