# How do I enable the Flip Active/Selected Bones options?

Tags: armature, selection-tools, pose-mode

Flip Active/Selected Bones with Armature in Pose Mode.
Currently the options are disabled. The goal is to get them enabled and functional.  The options respond to hover movements but mouse click has no effect in the panel UI or the 3D View window.

[image]

Click Image for larger view. Composed image. OS is Windows 10.

How do I get the options enabled?

- Active Only
- Extend

If I run the following script from the text editor window it is successful.

[image]

In related contrast,  the similar feature does works fully with options in

[Edit Mode].

[Edit Mode] successful.  [Pose Mode] not successful.

Its slightly interesting that the menu names are different in pose mode and edit mode.  The panel titles are the same.

[image]

link
https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_69_4/bpy.ops.pose.html

> bpy.ops.pose.select_mirror(only_active=False, extend=False)
>
> Mirror the bone selection
>
> Parameters:
>
> - only_active (boolean, (optional)) – Active Only, Only operate on the active bone
> - extend (boolean, (optional)) – Extend, Extend the selection

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get disabled behaviour on new single bone object?

Comment: are they really non-functional or only greyed out? for instance, when editing keyboard shortcuts, quite frequently i see greyed out checkboxes or input fields there, but you can enter values just fine.

Comment: @batFINGER The features are not enabled for a single new bone.  Of course I want to use the feature for X axis symmetrical armatures with mutliple bones .

Comment: @aliasguru I cannot click the options to enable them as implied by the UI.

Comment: could you please post the file? i am curious if it is something which gets saved or if it only appears on your system

Answer (score 1):

The operator properties are disabled when [global undo is disabled](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8263/935)

[image]

As for the menu variations, that would be to reflect the way the operator performs. Most of the select_mirror operators change the selection to be items on the opposite side, this can even lead to no active vertex in the selection. But the pose mode select_mirror operator will select the mirrored bone unless both bones are already selected when it will only change the active bone and not alter the selection.