# I can't change the parameters of a primitive after creating it in Blender 2.8

Tags: geometry

In Blender 2.7 you could achieve it like that: [How to edit Parameters for an Object after it is created?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/how-to-edit-parameters-for-an-object-after-it-is-created)

In Blender 2.8, when I create a cylinder for example I see the window to change the parameters of the primitive but I can't interact with it.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure? it looks fine to me.

Comment: Could you please add more info? Is this happening all the time or only sometimes? A complete Screenshot of the Blender interface? Are the properties really not editable, or do they just look like it?

Comment: The problem was that the "Global Undo" option was disabled as moonboots points out on his answer.

Comment: Good that you found a solution! But instead of editing the title to add "solved" better mark the correct answer as accepted. Check [ask] for more info, and later take the [tour] to learn more about the site.

Comment: My bad. I just fixed that, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: Top menu > *Edit* > *Preferences* > *System* > Enable *Global Undo*

[image]

Comment: Wow, it worked. Thanks a lot :). BTW, why would disabling Global Undo prevent users from changing a primitive's parameters?

Comment: it looks like Gandalf gives an answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8262/what-is-causing-disabled-options-when-adding-a-mesh-curve-object-to-the-scene

Comment: Oh, interesting. Thanks again. I couldn't upvote your answer due to my low reputation :(